# How to CSS style KendoUI-Dialog titlebar in 2 different ways when opening from the same Component?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a problem styling the KENDO UI dialog:

I have a component, lets call it WatComponent. Inside it,

- If the user clicks the "Forbidden" button, I want a *warning* styled dialog to pop-up, with yellow/orange colored titlebar,
- If the user clicks the "DANGER" button, I want an *error* styled dialog to pop-up, with red titlebar.

If I open the dialog via the DialogService:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
   title: this.danger ? 'DANGER!' : 'Warning!',
   content: WatDialogComponent
});
const userInfo = dialogRef.content.instance;
userInfo.danger = this.danger;
```

**How can I apply two different CSS styles (in any way) to make the titlebar appear in different colors when opened from the same component?**

I have tried

- adding a class to the `<div kendoDialogContainer class="myTitlebarClass"></div>` but of course, I didnt expect it to work (it didnt).
- giving the property `danger` some functionality to pass it to the titlebar, but unfortunately, it affects only titlebars inside `WatDialogComponent`, and I want to access the titlebar that is one step outside.
- looking for a property in the `DialogRef` that would let me do that.

Is there a straightaway solution to this that I'm missing? If not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the DialogRef API
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/api/DialogRef/
it includes the [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef) which can be used to get the host element and add a class:

```
this.dialog = this.dialogService.open({
    title: 'Warning',
    content: 'Warning'
});
this.dialog.dialog.location.nativeElement.classList.add('warning');
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RkW3zHFbmMuQqk4UDYNY?p=preview